# show(Model $model) is not working in Laravel 7

Tags: php, html, laravel, web

I have created a ModelController. In the `show(ModelName $model)`, I have defined the method: 
`

```
show(ModelName $model){
return response()->json(['data'=>$model]);
}
```

`, but it is not working as expected. It should return the model with its attributes, but it is returning an empty array.
My route is:

```
Route::resource('model','ModelController');
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class ModelName extends Model
{
    use Notifiable,SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];
}
```

All the other methods are returning expected values. Just the show method is not working properly. I tried using

```
show($id){
$model = ModelName::findOrFail($id)
return response()->json(['data'=>$model]);
}
```

This works perfectly, but I cannot use `show(Model $model)` this type of function call. I can retrieve user data by the same kind of method.
I can not figure out what the problem is. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I have used Model and ModelName as an example, in my project, they are defined in their own name and I hope there is no error in naming them.

Comment: I think that probably is the problem. You have type-hinted the argument on the method with "Model" but the class is named "ModelName".

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose because you have not included the "use..." statement in your example snippet of the code in the controller.

Comment: I have edited the code, now you may be clear. The problem is not that.

Comment: You can try to use explicit binding if it doesn't work
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#explicit-binding

Comment: Can you run `artisan route:list` and include the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your route list by cmd `php artisan route:list --name=Model`
match case in uri, is that same as your (Model $model),
$model should be same as {model} in uri (casesenstive)

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying your model in `ModelController` like so:

```
class ModelController extends Controller
{
    protect $model = ModelName::class;
}
```